# Objective gender-neutral pronoun?

Tags: pronouns, genderless-pronouns

> One would be evaluated based on:
>   1. what one does.
>   2. what is available to ----.

Some use "her" for the blank above. I want a gender-neutral pronoun. Can I simply use "one" again?

Comment: Is this a "fill in the blank" quiz question, or would you accept answers based on rewording?

Comment: @JamesK Rewording is accepted as well. But the general question on objective genderless pronoun remains.

Comment: Down-voters please mention their reasons.

Comment: "What you do". The next perhaps just  "What is available?" People often use "they" and "their" in the singular, for that reason. Similarly the antiquated "thou" was replaced with "you".

Comment: I have no idea what the question is or what the user wants or means.

Comment: Using "one" as a gender-neutral pronoun is formal and somewhat archaic, and I would recommend against using it, as there are many other options.  The easiest is to simply use the plural, *Candidates would be evaluated on: 1. What **they** do, and 2. What is available to **them***.  Either way the phrasing is still awkward, though.

Comment: @WeatherVane "One would be evaluated based on what you do" is ugly and confusing, though, because it shifts from *one* to *you* with no explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Briefly: My choice is

> **The candidates** would be evaluated based on what **they** do, and what is available to **them**.

In detail:

This question is a good example of how the English language changes over time.   This question attracted several good comments but needs at least one answer.

> One would be evaluated based on: 1. what one does. 2. what is available to ---.

There are several possible solutions that were mentioned:

### [A] available to *one*

This is very traditional writing, and sounds awkward to the modern ear:

> One would be evaluated based on: (1) what one does. (2) what is available to **one**.

No one speaks this way, not even royalty.  *This is not recommended*.

### [B] available to *him*

Using "him" is technically correct, similar to the use of "man" for "mankind".  Many people now say that using "him" implies the *male gender*, not just general "people".

> One would be evaluated based on: (1) what one does. (2) what is available to **him**.

This is *acceptable to some people, but not all people*.

### [C] available to *him or her*

This version is more inclusive, and also grammatically correct.

> One would be evaluated based on: (1) what one does. (2) what is available to **him or her**.

However, some people find that the use of "him or her" is a little awkward.  (It's not as bad as starting a letter "Dear Sir or Madam:".)   This is *fine*.

### [D] available to *her*

Using "her", when the gender is not known, is acceptable.

> One would be evaluated based on: (1) what one does. (2) what is available to **her**.

Using "her" instead of "him" flips the tradition on its head, and there is nothing wrong with it. I would guess this style became popular around the 1990s, and it is still popular.  Almost everyone who sees the sentence *will notice* that you used "her" instead of the traditional *him*, which may be desirable, or undesirable.

This is *better* to my ear, but some people prefer choice [C] above.

### [E] available to *them*,  (using the singular *they*)

Using the "singular they"/them has become especially popular the last few years to avoid *gendered* writing.  But it is not yet *universally* accepted.

> One would be evaluated based on: (1) what one does. (2) what is available to **them**.

Some audiences will feel this is *very progressive and correct*, but some people will find it strange that you switched from "one" (singular) to "them" (plural).

This is *fine* to me.

### [F] available to *them*, (using all plural)

If you wish to do "they" to avoid specifying a gender, I suggest rewriting to say

> **They** would be evaluated based on: (1) what they do (2) what is available to **them**.
>
> **The candidates** would be evaluated based on what **they** do, and what is available to **them**.

There is almost no difference between "one" was evaluated (singular) and "the candidates" *were* evaluated (plural).

Most people would read "one" was evaluated and assume that **more than one** was evaluated in **total**, and you are explaining the process for evaluating *each individual member* of a group, which occurred *multiple times*.

You also get to avoid using "one" referring to people, which is more modern.  American English, for example, almost never uses this construction ("One does not like it, does one?") although I guess it remains a little more popular in Britain.

*This is an excellent choice that will sound correct to the most people*.

You may also want to remove the numbers from the middle of the sentence, as it flows more smoothly without them.

### [G] one has available

I don't prefer to use the pronoun "one" very often.  If you *really* want want to continue using "one", then here is one more possibility.

In modern English, "one" sounds much better as a verb's subject than it does as an object.  You can rephrase the original sentence.

> One would be evaluated based on (1) what one does; (2) what one has available.

This is *fine*, but not my most preferred choice.